# Capacitor Filesystem returns error while using main functions

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I created a new app using capacitor 3, in this app I used the [Filesystem](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem) to perform some functions. I created a service to handle everything related to the filesystem, but when I went to use the functions I had some problems.

When using Android 11 to create a directory using the `mkdir()` function I get the following error:

> `Unable to create directory, unknow reason.`

Also on Android 11, when I try to create a file using only `writeFile()` it returns the following error:

> `FILE_NOTCREATED`

For Android 10 and below the `mkdir()` function works correctly, but the `writeFile()` function causes the app to crash without any errors. Also, if I try to change the `Diretory.ExternalStorage` to `Diretory.External` I can create a directory in Android 11, but it still crashes when writing a file.

Using Android 11, I tried to write a `txt` file with a simple string and with also with a small base64 string. When using `Diretory.External` I can write the base64 string in a new file, but when using the `Diretory.ExternalStorage` I got the `FILE_NOTCREATED` error.

I did all the configurations and followed the steps in the documentation to set up `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Several tests have been done on emulators and phones with different versions of Android.

**Tests with `writeFile()`**

```
Android 11
base64 + Diretory.External = success
string + Diretory.External = crash
base64 + Diretory.ExternalStorage = error
string + ExternalStorage  = error

Android 10 and below
base64 + Diretory.External = success
string + Diretory.External = crash
base64 + Diretory.ExternalStorage = success
string + ExternalStorage  = crash
```

---

**Android XML**

```
    <application 
      android:allowBackup="true" 
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true" 
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    >

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**MainFunction.ts**

```
testeFilesystem(): void {
    let path: string = 'test/project';
    this.filesystem.checkAndCreateDir(path).then(_ => {
        this.filesystem.writeFile(path, 'test.txt', 'test').then(_ => {
            this.uicontroller.presentToast('file saved');
        });
    })
}
```

**FilesystemService.ts**

```
checkAndCreateDir(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return Filesystem.readdir({
    path: path,
    directory: Directory.ExternalStorage
  }).then(_ => {
    return true;
  }).catch(_ => {
    return Filesystem.mkdir({
      path: path,
      directory: Directory.ExternalStorage,
      recursive: true
    }).then(_ => {
      return true;
    });
  });
}

writeFile(path: string, filename: string, content: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: path + filename,
    data: content,
    directory: Directory.ExternalStorage
  }).then(result => {
    if (result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

**Ionic Info**

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.7
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.10
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.13
  @angular/cli                  : 11.2.13
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:
  Capacitor CLI      : 3.0.0
  @capacitor/android : 3.0.0
  @capacitor/core    : 3.0.0
  @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:
  cordova-res : 0.15.3
  native-run  : 1.3.0

System:
  NodeJS : v14.16.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe)
  npm    : 6.14.12
  OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4656) on capacitor's github, maybe it can help you, in short it says:

> If you target SDK 30, then android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" will not work on Android 11+ devices.
> Google doesn't allow to programmatically access external shared files anymore. (Documents and ExternalStorage)

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app

Answer (score 6):

Got the same error ('FILE_NOTCREATED') on Android 12 using the following code after some writes:

```
// Save to filesystem
const resp = await Filesystem.writeFile({
  path: fileName,
  data, // base64 pdf
  directory: Directory.Documents,
});
```

The error occurs because of the same filename. After adding the current date with the following way, the error was solved:

```
const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/[,:\s\/]/g, '-');
const fileName = `myFile-${currentDate}.pdf`;
```

Be aware to replace all slashes because if not it will create sub-directories and if 'recursive: true' is not added the following error occurs on android:

```
Parent folder not found.
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the `Filesystem.writeFile` method cannot override the file with the same filename?